# managing click inside and outside of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click on `mdtop` should write just `top` in console.
Click on `mdtitle` should write just `title`
Click on `button` should write just `button` - if `mdwrap` IS NOT visible (default).
If `mdwrap` IS visible - click anywhere outside of `mdwrap` (including button and a lot of other elements) - should write `false`.

Here is my try, without success:

```js
$('.mdtop').on('click', function(){
  console.log('top');
});
$('.mdtitle').on('click', function(){
  console.log('title');
});
$('button').on('click', function(){
  console.log('button');
});
$(document).on('click', function(e){
 if($('#mdwrap').is(':visible') && !$(e.target).is('#mdwrap')){
  console.log('false');
 }
});
```

```css
.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mdwrap esc' id='mdwrap'>
<div class='mdtop' id='mdtop'>TOP</div>
<br>
<div class='mdtitle mditem' id='mdtitle'>TITLE</div>
</div>
<br>
<button>OUTSIDE</button>
```

Comment: You should stop using jQuery and starting using JS. See addEventListener, e.target, e.currentTarget, document.querySelector/document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Do you want to console.log innerHtml or anything sepcial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
$('.mdtop').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('top');
});
$('.mdtitle').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('title');
});
$('button').on('click', function(e){
  if(!$('#mdwrap').is(':visible')){
    e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('button');
  }
});
$(document).on('click', function(e){
 if($('#mdwrap').is(':visible')){
  console.log('false');
 }
});
```

```html
<div class='mdwrap esc' id='mdwrap'>
<div class='mdtop' id='mdtop'>TOP</div>
<br>
<div class='mdtitle mditem' id='mdtitle'>TITLE</div>
</div>
<br>
<button>OUTSIDE</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To stop propagation there is function inside `event` [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

```js
$('.mdtop').on('click', function(event) {
    /* event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('top'); */
    
    if (!$('#mdwrap').is(':visible')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log('top');
    }
});

$('.mdtitle').on('click', function(event) {
    /* event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('title'); */
    
    
    if (!$('#mdwrap').is(':visible')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log('title');
    }
});

$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    /* event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('button'); */
    
    if (!$('#mdwrap').is(':visible')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log('button');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ($('#mdwrap').is(':visible') && !$(e.target).is('#mdwrap')) {
        console.log('false');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='mdwrap esc' id='mdwrap'>
  <div class='mdtop' id='mdtop'>TOP</div>
  <div class='mdtitle mditem' id='mdtitle'>TITLE</div>
</div>
<button>OUTSIDE</button>
```

Comment: wrong - click on button gives `button`. Should be `false` if `mdwrap` is visible

Comment: @qadenza You can put your own logic. I was only giving you an example how to stop propagation.

Comment: my example is simplified, in reality I have a lot more elements on the page, hope not to write `event.stopPropagation` for a click on each of them.

Comment: @qadenza I have dumb it down for you. Please check.

Comment: Now I have double more to code for each click. Pls imagine browser's alert box. If it is not visible - each click works normally. If it is visible - there is no click on entire page, except on OK. That's what I want

Answer (score 1):

Tried to provide a generic solution without the use of `event.stopPropgation`

```js
        let isOutSideClick = false;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.mdtop').on('click', function() {
                console.log('top');
            });
   
            $('.mdtitle').on('click', function() {
                console.log('title');
            });
   
            $('button').on('click', function() {
                if (!isOutSideClick || $('#mdwrap').is(':visible') == false)
                    console.log('button');
            });

            $('#mdwrap').on('mouseover', function() {
                isOutSideClick = false;
            });

            $('#mdwrap').on('mouseleave', function() {
                isOutSideClick = true;
            });

        });

        $(document).on('click', function(e) {
            if ($('#mdwrap').is(':visible') && isOutSideClick)
                console.log('false');

        });
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class='mdwrap esc' id='mdwrap'>
        <div class='mdtop' id='mdtop'>TOP</div>
        <br>
        <div class='mdtitle mditem' id='mdtitle'>TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button>OUTSIDE</button>
</body>

</html>
```